# Why doesn't Acrobat trust a certificate issued by StartSSL?

Tags: certificate, adobe-acrobat

I created a free Client S/MIME and Authentication certificate on StartSSL.com and have imported it into Acrobat. I also created a .pfx file with the certificate chain and key using the command:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -out me.pfx -inkey mykey.key -in startssl-issued-cert.crt -certfile startcom-intermediate.crt
```

When I sign documents in Acrobat DC, it says the signature validity is UNKNOWN. It also says "THe signer's identity is unknown because it has not been included in your list of trusted certificates and non of its parent certificates are trusted certificates."

Further on down, it says "The path from the signer's certificate to an issuer's certificate was successfully built," so it seems to understand this is from StartSSL, which is trusted by default in Windows.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Acrobat doesn't trust the Windows certificate store by default, and Acrobat has its own, Adobe-approved trusted CA list. You can of course get a trusted certificate by paying around $400 for a certificate from one of Adobe's trusted providers. Or you can go into the certificate prefs in Acrobat and check the box for it to trust the Windows certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is called a [Self-signed Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) or snake oil certificate. It is not a verified certificate so Adobe won't inherently trust it. You can install the certificate to add it to your certificate store, this would prevent the error you are seeing. Others tho who open the PDF would see it is signed but would get the same result unless they as well install the certificate.

You may want to check out [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/certificate-signatures.html) page that goes into more details from Adobe. They offer a service which will do the signing for you without the burden of maintaining a certificate on your own.

Comment: I know what a self signed certificate is. As I said, I am using a certificate issued by StartSSL, which is a trusted root CA in most major OSes.